# samba upgrade do higher version

Tags: 16.04, samba

Is it possible to upgrade samba in Ubuntu 16.04 to higher version than 4.3.11 without upgrading system ?

It working as active directory domain controller for network around 300 workstations with roaming profiles etc.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to upgrade samba in Ubuntu 16.04 to higher version than 4.3.11 without upgrading system ?

Yes. Upgrading might be less hassle though.

Samba provides [downloads](https://pkgs.org/download/samba) for lots of versions and that includes a debian installer for Ubuntu 18.04 (v4.7.6) and 18.10 (v4.8.4). Mind that this will pull in the dependencies too but looking at the [package list](https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/samba) it is not that bad (libc6 would be the most difficult one).